# php return object of class from a function

Tags: php, json, forms, class

I'm using this class to create php FORM

http://smarttechdo.com/~avb/pfbc/api/

and I need to use this class through function, something like this

```
function getLogin() {
  Form::open ("login");
    echo "<legend>Login</legend>";
    Form::Hidden ("id");
    Form::Email ("Email Address:", "email", array("required" => 1));
    Form::Password ("Password:", "password", array("required" => 1));
    Form::Checkbox ("", "remember", array("1" => "Remember me"));
    Form::Button ("Login");
    Form::Button ("Cancel", "button", array("onclick" => "history.go(-1);"));
  Form::close (false);

  return ???
}
```

How to do that ?

EDIT : I need to return as json data

```
$var = getLogin();
echo json_encode($var);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `Form` is `static` so you don't need return any value. You can use in other place just in the same way as in this function.

Comment: sorry you are right but I need to return as json data (like as edit my post)

Answer (score 1):

Like said mitch, Form only uses static methods, you have two choices :

1. Don't return anything
2. Try to find a static method inside Form class, that return your current instance. Maybe a Form::get('Login') ?

Comment: sorry you are right but I need to return as json data (like as edit my post)

Comment: Maybe the real problem is to understand your need...
Why do you have to send a string / json? Why not sending HTML data via AJAX?